# Selecting max value across columns opposed to across rows

Tags: sqlite

I am attempting to select the max value within separate columns per a dimension listed in a row as so;

```
 Input Dataset
 Person|Date#1  |Date#2  |Date#3  |Date#4
 ------+--------+--------+--------+---------
 Matt  |12/01/18|01/15/19|02/15/19|04/15/18
 Dave  |01/15/18|01/02/19|03/15/19|11/01/19


Desired result


 Input Dataset
 Person|Max Date|
 ------+--------+
 Matt  |02/15/19|
 Dave  |11/01/19|
```

Comment: Start by changing the dates your're storing to one of the formats supported by [sqlite date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), as those can, unlike what you're using now, be meaningfully compared and ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix up your tables to a proper format like `YYYY-mm-dd` so the table looks like so:

```
Person      Date#1      Date#2      Date#3      Date#4    
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
Matt        2018-12-01  2019-01-15  2019-02-15  2018-04-15
Dave        2018-01-15  2019-01-12  2019-03-15  2019-11-01
```

it becomes a trivial

```sql
SELECT Person, max("Date#1", "Date#2", "Date#3", "Date#4") AS "Max Date" FROM mytable;
```

```
Person      Max Date  
----------  ----------
Matt        2019-02-15
Dave        2019-11-01
```

Remember, [sqlite does **not** have any date or time types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype). It uses strings or numbers to hold those values. When storing dates as strings, they have to be formatted in a way that can be compared meaningfully. `'04/15/18'` is greater than `'01/15/19'` because the character 4 is greater than the character 1. None of the standard [time string formats](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) have that problem.